# How to say which function in a sequence of functions fails with one match only

Tags: rust

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c6d1d9b99ed30407e8d6d657641a0577

I have

```
fn f(i : i32) -> Option<i32> {return Some(1);}
fn g(i : i32) -> Option<i32> {return Some(1);}
fn h(i : i32) -> Option<i32> {return Some(1);}
```

I have

```
 let x = f(1).map(|j|g(j).map(|k|h(k)));
```

Now, I want to add an error message to say which function has failed. I can print in the map. But it´s difficult to read.

I would like something like that:

```
match h(g(f(1)?)?)
{
    Some(Some(Some(x)))=> print "success"
    Some(Some(None)) => print f has failed
    Some(None) => print g has failed
    None => print h has failed
}
```

Comment: Well `Option` is'nt really made for this, and nested ones are not really something you commonly want, you preffer them flattened most of the time. Calling `?` will unwrap the Option so that's not what you want. `Option::and_then` is made for you to chain function like this, so computing `x` in one Option would be `f(1).and_then(g).and_then(h)` but you would loose which function failed. There is no nice way to do it other than merging what you already done: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ddf942dbb0054dffac95463216940dea).

Comment: What you could do is write your own Monad: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=71deb585395254c8bf0558a3b76ed00a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map()` or `and_then()` are kind of meant to collapse failure/None cases into a single type. It seems like you are trying to fight this and wish to keep the error origin information, but that's not what they do.

From what I see, I would say your best solution is something like this:

```
let x = f(1).ok_or_else(|| "f failed")?;
let y = g(x).ok_or_else(|| "g failed")?;
let z = h(y).ok_or_else(|| "h failed")?;
```

with that being called in a function returning a `Result`. This way, you have information about which function failed in the `Err`. Which you can then deal with in a single, appropriate place. Printing things on the spot is anyway not something you'd want to keep in a serious application.

Comment: Why `ok_or_else()` for string literals? `ok_or()` will suffice.

Comment: True, it was out of habit: when using real errors you want to skip creating the error when not needed. In this case it's useless, but if that code is used as a base to elaborate and introduce real errors, it might be useful.